# Unable to load php after a dorked install of php 7.1

Tags: debian, wordpress, apache2, php7

After a messy installation of php7.1 on Debian 8 (used the ppa for Ubuntu), I managed to revert to the correct package of php7.1. However, I believe I am missing perhaps a few key modules.

The problem is that a wordpress site that worked fine before the upgrade from php5 fails with http error 500. Yes, wordpress seems to supports php7.1. The virtualservers are managed by virtualmin.

My apache2 log shows:

```
require_once(/home/example/public_html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/example/public_html/wp-load.php on line 37
```

***Right now, php files are being downloaded on this server, instead of processing them.***

However I hadnt changed the permissions, and the permissions are still correct. The user and group is example.example. In /cat/passwd, this user exists. Other sites seem to work fine. I have installed the following modules:

```
php7.1-curl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql php7.1-xml php7.1-xmlrpc
```

which are the dependencies documented in wordpress docs.

I should add that only the ssl version doesnt work. The http version shows the default apache page.

My virtualhost configuration (It's a bit messy probably because its generated by virtualmin).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1003"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias webmail.example.com
ServerAlias admin.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/example/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.1
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php7.1.fcgi .php7.1
</Directory>
<Directory /home/example/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RemoveHandler .php7.1
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
Alias /dav /home/example/public_html
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "example.com"
AuthUserFile /home/example/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "example.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/example/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://example.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://example.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
IPCCommTimeout 41
php_admin_value engine Off
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 5.196.66.43:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1003"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias webmail.example.com
ServerAlias admin.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/example/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.1
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php7.1.fcgi .php7.1
</Directory>
<Directory /home/example/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RemoveHandler .php7.1
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
Alias /dav /home/example/public_html
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "example.com"
AuthUserFile /home/example/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "example.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/example/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://example.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://example.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/example/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/example/ssl.key
IPCCommTimeout 41
SSLCACertificateFile /home/example/ssl.ca
php_admin_value engine Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me get to the root of this. I tried removing the php7.1 lines, but didnt do anything.

The .htaccess files:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blog.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^supernova.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://supernova.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff”
</ifModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Debian 8
apache2
php 7.1, and 5.6
```

Comment: Do you have the correct PHP 7.1 module (.so file) present in the Apache modules folder? On my setup (CentOS 6), this is /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so - there is then /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf which tells Apache that if it has successfully loaded this module, it should pass all *.php files to it for processing, meaning the pages will be rendered and served rather than downloaded.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Next time I'll check this. My sites were offline for too long, so I switched from virtualmin to i-mscp and purged and reinstalled all my packages. apache is fine now.